# Convert iDictionary<TKey,TValue> into IDictionary<TSomeProperty, ICollection<TValue>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` referencing my items by a `TKey` hash.

How could I *group by* those values by, say, the result of `EquivalenceClass TKey.GetEquivalenceClass()`? The result would then fit into a `IDictionary<EquivalenceClass, ICollection<TValue>>`

A more concrete example, maybe: given

```
public enum PlayerPositionGroup {Attacker, Defender}
public class Player{
  public PlayerPositionGroup GetPositionGroup(){...}
}
```

turn

```
IDictionary<string, Player> SoccerPlayersByName
```

into

```
IDictionary<PlayerPositionGroup, ICollection<Player>>
```

Comment: Use a lookup instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SoccerPlayersByName
.Values
.GroupBy(v => v.GetPositionGroup())
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());
```